# After installation of TLP I have notice a increase of 5 up to 7 seconds on boot in xubuntu

Tags: boot, xubuntu, power-management

I have intalled TLP on xubuntu and I notice a increase of time btw 5 up to 7 seconds on boot time according dmesg output and I have now some ACPI Warnings on boot, I'm attaching my dmesg output and my grub file. What can I do to reduce 5 or 7 sec. on boot time? How to remove these warnings on boot? My kernel is 3.11.0.26, [   26.568413] this is my boot time.My laptop is DELL inspiron 3521 BIOS version A12.
Thanks for now Vladi.
[image: dmesg |grep ACPI output]
[image: My Grub config.]

Comment: Did you uninstall TLP and check if the symptoms disappear?

Comment: Not yet, I didn't uninstall TLP

Comment: I suggest to do it.